# Google Analytics installation confusion

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I am trying to install GA on a new WordPress website (PHP). From the 'tracking code' section I do understand they need to go right after the opening  tag. Did and the status says "Tracking Not Installed" . From the status learn more button I understand it needs to go right  before the  tag. I have done that the status is still "Tracking Not Installed".

Interesting enough, when I check the GA data I do see who visited the website, but not the chrome users

[image: immediately after the opening <body> tag] [image: Paste it immediately before the closing </head> tag]

Here is the code I get in View-source when in the body tag

```
 <body class="page page-id-8 page-template-default" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <script>

   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-0000000-1', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

 </script> 

    <header class="tc-header clearfix row-fluid" role="banner">
```

Here is the code I get in View-source when in the head tag.

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />

      <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-0000000-1', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not really any difference between using the php version and just pasting the standard tracking code into your header template.

If you are not familiar enough with WordPress to edit that template, I would recommend using a Google Analytics plugin.  There are many.

Comment: So just paste the standard tracking code into your header template.

Comment: I have done tried that again right now, and still not picking that it is installed

Comment: When you look at the site, can you see the tracking code when you view source?

Comment: Then it is working fine.  Give Google a bit of time to update the status.

Comment: Was thinking the same.. It has been over 24 hours now

Comment: It should not take that long.  Can you post exactly what you see in the source?

Comment: Edited site name and UA 

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-0000000-1', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

Comment: Can you add this to the original question (so it can be formatted) and include a few lines of the code that is above and below the script?

Comment: Try moving it into the `<head>`, and not the `<body>`

Comment: Tried in the <head> and no luck either

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem recently. It takes a while to show that its tracking data. One thing you can do to test if its working is check the real-time report. If its showing visits when you visit the site then the code is installed properly.

Comment: It shows only when I go to website from safari or firefox but not when using chrome